# Colab TPU error - InvalidArgumentError: Unsupported data type for TPU: string, caused by output cond_8/Identity_1:0

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu

I get above error in colab TPU from the code below. Original model had epochs, steps_per_epoch and batch but removed that while debugging. Not sure what the issue is as I do not see a string.
None TPU version of code works. Most of the code is stock code with some modifications made. I tested the code to ensure images loaded properly.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import os
import PIL
import csv
import shutil
import numpy as np
import sys
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import gc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3


from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau


resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
# This is the TPU initialization code that has to be at the beginning.
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)


list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(gcs_pattern))

# Reads an image from a file, decodes it into a dense tensor, and resizes it
# to a fixed shape.
def parse_image(filename):
  parts = tf.strings.split(filename, os.sep)
  label = parts[-2]

  image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [400, 400])
  return image, label

list_ds = list_ds.map(parse_image)


def create_model():
         pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (400, 400,3), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')

 input_tensor=None, input_shape=(1024, 1024,3))

         for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
                    if layer.name == 'mixed1':
                                    break

                    layer.trainable = False

         last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7')
         last_output = last_layer.output

         from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
         from tensorflow.keras import regularizers


         x = Flatten()(last_output)
         x = layers.Dense(1024,  activation= 'relu')(x)
         x = layers.Dropout(.2)(x)
         x = layers.Dense(4, activation= 'softmax')(x)
         modelin = Model(pre_trained_model.input, x)
         return modelin



def get_callbacks(name_weights, patience_lr):
    mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint(name_weights, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_acc', mode='max')
#     reduce_lr_loss = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.1, patience=patience_lr, verbose=1, epsilon=1e-4, mode='min')
    return [mcp_save] #, reduce_lr_loss]


batch_size = 16 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

for i in range(5):

    dataset = list_ds.shuffle(buffer_size = 2280)  
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    val = dataset.skip(i*456).take(456).batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(4)

    train = dataset.skip(i*456+456).take(1824).concatenate(dataset.take(456*i)).batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(15)


    name_weights = "/content/drive/My Drive/Plant/final_model_fold_D512_I400_mix_1_7_" + str(i) + ".{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}.h5"
    # callbacks = get_callbacks(name_weights = name_weights, patience_lr=10)


    with strategy.scope():
       modelinc = create_model()
       modelinc.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'])

    modelinc.fit(
                train,
                epochs=5)


    print(modelinc.evaluate(val)) 
    K.clear_session()

    del name_weights
    del callbacks

    gc.collect()
'''
```

-   -

Error:

```
          Epoch 1/5    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------    InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call  last)
       <ipython-input-4-bbe01274450b> in <module>()
           31     modelinc.fit(
           32                 train,
       ---> 33                 epochs=5)
           34 
           35 
          10 frames    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
           64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
           65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access    ---> 66       return method(self, *args,  
**kwargs)
           67 
           68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,       validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,       sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,       validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers,       use_multiprocessing)
          853                 context.async_wait()
          854               logs = tmp_logs  # No error, now safe to assign to logs.    --> 855                  callbacks.on_train_batch_end(step, logs)
          856         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
          857 
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
          387     """
          388     if self._should_call_train_batch_hooks:    --> 389       logs = self._process_logs(logs)
          390       self._call_batch_hook(ModeKeys.TRAIN, 'end', batch, logs=logs)
          391 
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in _process_logs(self, logs)
          263     """Turns tensors into numpy arrays or Python scalars."""
          264     if logs:    --> 265       return tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
          266     return {}
          267 
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in to_numpy_or_python_type(tensors)
          521     return t  # Don't turn ragged or sparse tensors to NumPy.
          522     --> 523   return nest.map_structure(_to_single_numpy_or_python_type, tensors)
          524 
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py  in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
          615 
          616   return pack_sequence_as(    --> 617       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
          618       expand_composites=expand_composites)
          619 
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py  in <listcomp>(.0)
          615 
          616   return pack_sequence_as(    --> 617       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
          618       expand_composites=expand_composites)
          619 
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in _to_single_numpy_or_python_type(t)
          517   def _to_single_numpy_or_python_type(t):
          518     if isinstance(t, ops.Tensor):    --> 519       x = t.numpy()
          520       return x.item() if np.ndim(x) == 0 else x
          521     return t  # Don't turn ragged or sparse tensors to NumPy.
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in numpy(self)
          959     """
          960     # TODO(slebedev): Consider avoiding a copy for non-CPU or remote tensors.    --> 961     maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
          962     return maybe_arr.copy() if isinstance(maybe_arr, np.ndarray) else maybe_arr
          963 
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _numpy(self)
          927       return self._numpy_internal()
          928     except core._NotOkStatusException as e:    --> 929       six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)
          930 
          931   @property
          /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value,    from_value)
          InvalidArgumentError: Unsupported data type for TPU: string, caused    by output cond_8/Identity_1:0
```

Comment: I noticed I did not scale the input which fixes the above issue but creates a new error. TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType' I think this error might be because I need to convert the label data to a class

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I ran into the same error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Unsupported data type for TPU: string, caused by output Pad:0`. My code works on my local GPU but not Cloud TPU.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Have you guys resolved this?